# Workaround to android:singleLine for items in a ListView without sacrificing itemClickListening functionality

Tags: android

Due to this [feature](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) in ListViews, items cannot gain focus if you want ListView to be able to listen to click events through onItemClick or onListItemClick. Now this is a problem if you want a TextView in an item to be single-lined at the same time. Because if you set `android:inputType="text"`, the TextView somehow becomes "clickable", thus gaining focus.

I'm currently using `android:singleLine="true"` as a workaround, but it is listed as depreciated. Are there any "legit" or non-depreciating methods in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try..........

`android:maxLines`

Comment: or did you mean android:layout_weight?

Comment: +1 for maxLines, but I'm confused with layout_weight, how would that help me?

Comment: Ignore it...I have something in my mind that would be totally different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`inputType` really makes more sense for `EditText`. If you really want to use it, can't you just set `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`?

Also, look into `android:ellipsize` if you don't like the first solution.

Comment: I tried clickable and focusable. inputType seems to override them both.